# ggplot map plot fails when limits set with coord_map

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm trying to limit a map plot to a specific area.  `coord_map` [is preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644262/geographical-borders-incomplete-using-geom-polygon-for-plotting-map-ggplot2) to `scale_x_continuous` and y equivalent, since the latter mess up the polygons.  But here I'm finding it fails for some reason.  Here's my code (downloads a 57kb shapefile):

```
require(maptools)
require(ggplot2)
download.file('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46043231/UK.zip', "uk.zip", method="internal", mode="wb")
unzip('uk.zip')
uk = readShapePoly('uk_outline_1000m.shp')
print(bbox(uk))
        min       max
x  259.9625  655566.4
y 7211.7025 1218558.9
uk2 = fortify(uk)
(p = ggplot(uk2, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + geom_polygon() + coord_equal())
```

[image]

But when `coord_map` is used the plot disappears:

```
p + coord_map(xlim=c(0, 630000), ylim=c(0, 1000000))
```

[image]

Any idea what's going on??

Comment: this seems to be a projection issue. You cannot use `coord_map()` without explicitly defining the projection in this particular case. I suppose you are using epsg 27700.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would try something like this to test a few options.

```
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(latticeExtra)
```

### Download and read the data

```
download.file('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/46043231/UK.zip',
              "uk.zip", method="internal", mode="wb")
unzip('uk.zip')
uk <- readOGR(dsn = getwd(), layer = 'uk_outline_1000m')
```

Data is assumed to use OSGB 1936 / British National Grid.

More about at [SpatialReference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/)

```
proj4string(uk) <- CRS('+init=epsg:27700') # EPSG 27700
extent(uk)
bb.uk <- as(extent(uk), 'SpatialPolygons') # a spatial object
proj4string(bb.uk) <- CRS('+init=epsg:27700')
```

Write projected shapefile of uk bbox. I'll write it out to map layers with QGIS. It will be my reference system.

```
writeOGR(as(bb.uk, 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame'),
         dsn = getwd(),
         layer = 'bbuk2_bng', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

The desired bounding box. Using projected coordinates

```
bb.uk2 <- as(extent(c(0, 630000), c(0, 1000000)), 'SpatialPolygons')
proj4string(bb.uk2) <- CRS('+init=epsg:27700')
```

Write projected shapefile of user bbox

```
writeOGR(as(bb.uk2, 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame'),
         dsn = getwd(),
         layer = 'bbuk2user_bng', driver = 'ESRI Shapefile')
```

### QGis map using British National Grid EPSG:27700

[image: QGIS map EPSG 27700]

### Plot projected layers

**Base plot**

```
plot(uk, col = 'grey50', axes = T, xlim=c(-50000, 705566.4),
     ylim=c(-50000, 1325000))
plot(bb.uk, add = T)
plot(bb.uk2, border = 'red', add = T)
```

[image: base plot epsg 27700]

**spplot**

I took a arbitrary window to expand plot area.

```
sp::spplot(uk, zcol = 'NAME_ISO', scales = list(draw = TRUE), 
           xlim=c(-50000, 705566.4), ylim=c(-50000, 1325000),
           col.regions="grey90") +
  latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(bb.uk, fill = NA, col = 'blue')) +
  latticeExtra::layer(sp.polygons(bb.uk2, fill = NA, col = 'red'))
```

[image: spplot epsg 27700]

**ggmap** with projected layers

```
uk.df = fortify(uk) # admin 
bbuk.df <- fortify(bb.uk) # country bbox extent
bbuk2.df <- fortify(bb.uk2) # user bbox extent
```

plot it

```
p <- ggplot() + geom_polygon(data = uk.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) + 
  geom_polygon(data = bbuk.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
               colour = 'blue', fill = NA) +
  geom_polygon(data = bbuk2.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),
               colour = 'red', fill = NA) +
  coord_equal() # cartesian
p
```

[image: ggplot epsg27700 - cartesian]

plot it with user bounding box

```
p + coord_equal(xlim=c(0, 630000), ylim=c(0, 1000000))
```

[image: gplot epsg27700 - cartesian user box]

### Now ggplot with geographic (unprojected) coordinates

WGS84 Unprojected Coordinate Reference System

```
p.wgs84 <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # WGS84 Long Lat
```

Convert projected layer to WGS84

```
uk.wgs89 <- spTransform(uk, p.wgs84)
```

Geographic bbox uk

```
bbuk.wgs84 <- as(as(extent(uk.wgs89), 'SpatialPolygons'),
                 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame')
```

Geographic bbox of user extent

```
bbuk2.wgs84 <- spTransform(bb.uk2, p.wgs84)
bbuk2.wgs84 <- as(bbuk2.wgs84, 'SpatialPolygonsDataFrame')
```

Plot it with ggplot and cartesian map

```
uk.df = fortify(uk.wgs89) # admin 
bbuk.df <- fortify(bbuk.wgs84) # country bbox extent
bbuk2.df <- fortify(bbuk2.wgs84) # user bbox extent
```

[image: ggplot epsg4326]

The result is not what I'd expect. I don't figure out why the red box is distorted.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, this looks like the way to go (although its disappointing coord_map isn't more CRS-agnostic).  But one thing that does confuse me is how your example's coord_equal is seemingly ignored (see the x/y scale difference). It actually plots more accurately this way than the equirectangular projection that `coord_equal` _'should'_ produce with a latlon CRS. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @geotheory. Let me think about it.

Comment: @geotheory I don't know exactly what is going on with unprojected coordinates and ggplot but this is something to go further and study.